# OnMouseOver drop down not coming

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

`onmouseOver` of `eacuser` i want to show the change password as a dropdown(as can seen in attached image) but with my code changes i am getting change password next to eacuser link.Can anyone please give me some hint how to achieve.I attached the two image file.please check for reference
  [image]
[image]

```
<div id="appLinks">
  <ul id="appLinks_list" class="nav">
    <span id="appLink_csrname" class="ui-state-default csrname"><a onmouseover="onMouseOver()">eacuser</span>
      <li id="appLink_chngpwd" class="ui-state-default chngpwd">Change Password</li>
      <li id="appLink_about" rtlOrder="3"><a href="javascript:openAboutDialog();"><img src="${link.getContextPath()}${msg.get("icon.information")}" border="0px;" align="top">About</a></li>
      <li id="appLink_logout" rtlOrder="2"><a href="$link.getContextPath()/logout.do"><img src="${link.getContextPath()}${msg.get("icon.logout")}" border="0px;" align="top">LogOut</a></li>
      <li id="appLink_help" rtlOrder="1"><a target="eachelp" href="$msg.get("eac.helpPath")"><img src="${link.getContextPath()}${msg.get("icon.help")}"  border="0px;" align="top">Help</a></li>
    </span>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".csrname").mouseleave(function(){
      //$('#appLink_chngpwd').hide();
      $(".csrname li").css("display","none"); 
    });
    $(".csrname").mouseover(function(){
      //$('#appLink_chngpwd').show();
    $(".csrname li").css("display","block"); 
  });
</script>
```

Comment: First of all your document.ready is missing the closing bracket

Comment: It must be because of adding the property "block" to your li. Anyways  please create a fiddle.

Comment: 1. missing opening tag of your last `<span>` 2. `<span>` not allowed as child of `<ul>`! please use a propper IDE ...

Comment: pls attach a jsfiddle demo ...

Comment: @Nano I think he has closed the same span twice?

Comment: 3. when you are writing `$(".csrname li")`, then `li` should be the child of `.csrname`

Comment: 4. all in all its a invalid html markup, so this will behave differently in different browsers.

Comment: YOu have you're HTML all messed up. That's a HTML/CSS problem that you nave. First you CANT have a <span> as a child of <UL>, it must be a <li>. Even if that worked you have <span><a></span> You dont close the <a>

Instead of using <span> use <li> if you want that first LI to be different than the others use li:first-child{} in CSS so the style will be only to that one LI. Then you probably need to give some position Absolute to the DIV you want to display on mouseover. Provide some FIDDLE and I can change the code.

Comment: You should use jQuery show() and hide() functions instead of .css('display', 'block') or .css('display', 'none').

Comment: @Uday Konduru post your CSS also.

Answer (score 0):

use this,

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $('#appLink_chngpwd').hide(); 
        $(".csrname").mouseover(function(){
      $('#appLink_chngpwd').show(); 
        }); 
          $(".csrname").mouseleave(function(){
      $('#appLink_chngpwd').hide(); 
        });
           });  
</script>
```

Comment: The problem its not in the jQuery. If you look closer

Comment: There was syntax error.above code is working fine,you can check

Comment: done the changes and tx for ur help but still the same problem exist, i want change password to come as drop down option as displayed in the attached image , but it is coming right to eacuser.

Comment: have you tried this             <ul>
        <li id="appLink_chngpwd" class="ui-state-default chngpwd">Change Password</li>
  </ul>

Comment: <li><span id="appLink_csrname" class="ui-state-default csrname"><a id="eacuser">eacuser</span> 
  <ul> 
        <li id="appLink_chngpwd" class="ui-state-default chngpwd">Change Password</li>
  </ul>
  </li>

Comment: @Mr7-itsurdeveloper it is working thank you for your valuable suggestion n help..

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have used like below.

```
 $(".csrname li").css("display","none");
```

It means you are making display none for child property of span having class .csrname

At present in your code, "Change Password" is sibling element not a child.

So change your code like below.

```
 $(".csrname + li#appLink_chngpwd").css("display","none");
```